# SeleniumUI & Windows Scheduled Task - Close Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I have an application that performs some UI testing using Selenium UI and Internet Explorer.
I start the Internet Explorer webdriver, perform the tests and closing the explorer and the console using webDriver.Quit()
That works nice when I execute it from my Visual Studio, or even executing an external script with my user account. But, when I try it to run it in a Windows Scheduled Task (ie, once a day), the Internet Explorer console (IeDriver.exe) does not close, resulting in a lot of IEDriver.exe running in few days, making our development server unstable.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be an issue with the user privileges that the task is running under. Does the task have "Run with highest privileges" checked?

HTH,
Charles